# Unfreezing the Frozen Synapse Tournament

Tags: discussion, community-event

Our Frozen Synapse tourney has been inactive for a few months. Let's change that.

I will now be using [**this Trello**](https://trello.com/board/frozen-synapse-tourney/4f304f30904f71da711d25b3) to organize the remaining games. Here's what going to happen:

- Every game now has a hard deadline - two weeks per game, as previously arranged.
- The **home player** *must* comment on their game's card as he challenges the away player to a game.
- The **losing player** *must* comment with the outcome of each game. (The winning player *should* do so as well.)

Your comments will be used to assign an outcome to the game if necessary and advance the tourney to the next phases. (e.g., If the deadline passes and we hear nothing from the home player, the away player will win by default.)

The next set of deadlines is February 26th. Please check [the brackets](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/29281634/Frozen%20Synapse%20Tournament%20Bracket.png), [the tourney chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1558/frozen-synapse-tournament) and/or [the trello](https://trello.com/board/frozen-synapse-tourney/4f304f30904f71da711d25b3) for more information.

Comment: So, we're hosting a Synapse Tournament, is what you're saying.

Comment: @GraceNote [Relevant](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=2933044#2933044).